# Cross-Origin Request Blocked React y Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, cors

Tengo una carpeta que se llama example.com, dentro de esta carpeta está la carpeta frontend y backend

En el archivo /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
listen       [::]:80;
server_name  example.com;
root         /var/www/html/example.com/frontend/build;
index index.html index.htm;

location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #whatever port your app runs on
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   proxy_redirect off;
}

location /api {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/api;
  proxy_redirect off;
 }
}
```

En el index.js de mi api:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const dbConnect = require('./config/db');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({extended: true}));

app.use('/api/dashboard/', require('./routes/dashboard'));
app.use('/api/provider/', require('./routes/provider'));
app.use('/api/report/', require('./routes/report'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
dbConnect(); // Db connection

//home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send("hello world")
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Running server port ${PORT}`)
});
```

La aplicación se visualiza correctamente, sin embargo no se muestra ninguna información porque me muestra un error de cors.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Nos faltan datos: veo que tienes 3 servidores: una instancia de Nginx en el puerto 80, otra instancia (de NodeJS?) en el puerto 3000 y otra más en el puerto 3001. Pero no sabemos qué URL usas para cargar tu aplicación React y a qué URL hace dicha aplicación la petición que falla

Comment: Tengo un solo servidor en Ubuntu instalado NGINX y PM2. En este server en la ruta /var/www/html/ se encuentra la carpeta example.com y dentro de esta la carpeta backend y frontend.
El frontend (React) corre en el puerto 3000 y el backend(nodejs) en el puerto 3001

Comment: Entonces ¿para qué usas Nginx? Tal y como lo tienes el navegador debería acceder exclusivamente por el puerto 80

Comment: Si detengo el servicio de NGINX por el puerto 80 accedo a la pagina  "Welcome NGINX" y para acceder al frontend debo acceder : http://IP:3000 y si puedo acceder al backend: http://IP:3001, pero en la consola del navegador me sigue apareciendo el error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3001/api/dashboard. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Comment: Aunque se trate del mismo dominio, el navegador trata cada puerto como diferente sitio y, ya que estás usando _Express_, puedes aplicar el paquete [CORS](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) para enviar los encabezados correctos y solucionar el problema.